# Why is the concurrently-written boolean value still true after being set to false?

Tags: concurrency, go, mutex, dining-philosopher

I'm writing a Philosophers Dining solution in Go. My solution is simple: check if both forks are available. If so, pick both up. If not, leave both be.

However, I'm running into a weird concurrency error, whereby a fork's availability is still true even after explicitly being set to false. My `Fork` is declared like so:

```
type Fork struct {
    mu    sync.Mutex
    avail bool
}

func (f *Fork) PickUp() bool {
    f.mu.Lock()
    if f.avail == false {
        f.mu.Unlock()
        return false
    }
    f.avail = false
    fmt.Println("set false")
    f.mu.Unlock()
    return true
}

func (f *Fork) PutDown() {
    f.mu.Lock()
    f.avail = true
    f.mu.Unlock()
}
```

When a Philosopher calls `PickUp()`, the program will wait for the mutex lock; if, at that point, the fork is available, the `Fork` sets its availability boolean to false and returns true to indicate the operation was successful.

The Philosopher is written like so:

```
type Philosopher struct {
    seatNum int
}

func (phl *Philosopher) StartDining(forkList [9]Fork) {
    for {
        fmt.Println(forkList[phl.seatNum], phl.seatNum)
        if forkList[phl.seatNum].PickUp() {
            fmt.Println("Philo ", phl.seatNum, " picked up fork ", phl.seatNum)

            if forkList[phl.getLeftSpace()].PickUp() { 
                fmt.Println("Philo ", phl.seatNum, " picked up fork ", phl.getLeftSpace())
                fmt.Println("Philo ", phl.seatNum, " has both forks; eating...")
                time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

                forkList[phl.seatNum].PutDown()
                forkList[phl.getLeftSpace()].PutDown()
                fmt.Println("Philo ", phl.seatNum, " put down forks.")
            } else {
                forkList[phl.seatNum].PutDown()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*(Note: The `getLeftSpace()` function has been excluded because its implementation is irrelevant; it simply gets the index of the leftward space.)*

The implementation of the `Philosopher` is very simple: it checks to see if it can get the first fork. Then, it checks to see if it can get the second fork; if it can't, it puts down the first fork. If it can, it holds both for 5 seconds, then puts both down. I've limited this to two philosophers for testing purposes.

---

However, this isn't working properly. Philosopher 0 picks up the first fork, and then the second fork. I have verified that the availability of these forks have been set to false. By this point, Philosopher 1 is locked by the mutex. However, once Philo 0 has released the mutex, Philo 1 enters the function.

The expected result at this point would be for the `PickUp()` function to return false; as the fork is no longer available, it cannot be picked up. However, the function does not do this; it returns true and allows Philo 1 to pick up the fork!

Even more mysterious, by the time Philo 1 goes to pick up the fork, the availability of the fork is `true`, even though Philo 0 explicitly set them to false! Here is my debug output:

```
{{0 0} true} 0                       # Fork 0 is available
set false                            # Fork 0 has been picked up
Philo  0  picked up fork  0          # Repsonse from Philo 0 confirming the above
{{0 0} true} 0                       # Fork 1 is available
set false                            # Fork 1 has been picked up
Philo  0  picked up fork  1          # Response from Philo 0 confirming the above
Philo  0  has both forks; eating...  # As Philo 0 has both forks, they can now eat...

{{0 0} true} 1                     **# Philo 1 checks Fork 0's availability, **which is true?**
set false                            # Philo 1 sets Fork 0's availability to false
Philo  1  picked up fork  1          # Response of ^
{{0 0} true} 1                       
set false                            
Philo  1  picked up fork  2
Philo  1  has both forks; eating...
```

Philo 1 should never have been able to pick up the fork. Since Philo 1 was locked by a mutex, and the only two exit conditions for `PickUp` are *after* the availability is false, the fork could not possibly have been available.

Yet it is. Why is this? How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is almost certainly the signature of your `StartDining` method:

```
func (phl *Philosopher) StartDining(forkList [9]Fork)
```

Arrays in Go are passed by value, so every time you call `StartDining`, you're passing in copies of the forks. The philosophers are dining at completely separate tables!

Try passing in a pointer to an array instead.

Comment: Or perhaps better yet, use a slice.

Comment: Indeed, I should probably have used a slice for this. Pass-by-value  will take some getting used to! Thanks, though!

Comment: Quick question: If the array is copied, why would Philosopher 1 have been locked by the mutex?

Comment: I don't understand why you think Philosopher 1 was locked by the mutex.

Comment: @Evan Because Philo 1 wasn't running until _after_ Philo 0 had released the forks.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean anything. The order in which goroutines run is unspecified, so it's probably just a coincidence.